# How to break line for long author name?

Tags: author, ieeeconf

I am using the IEEE template for ISBI conference at http://2020.biomedicalimaging.org/full-paper-instructions

The author section is inserted in the \name tag. If I put too long author. i.e. six authors, how can we break the author into two line. I have used `\\` but it does not work

```
% Template for ISBI paper; to be used with:
%          spconf.sty  - ICASSP/ICIP LaTeX style file, and
%          IEEEbib.bst - IEEE bibliography style file.
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{spconf,amsmath,graphicx}

% Example definitions.
% --------------------
\def\x{{\mathbf x}}
\def\L{{\cal L}}

% Title.
% ------
\title{AUTHOR GUIDELINES FOR ISBI 2018 PROCEEDINGS MANUSCRIPTS}
%
% Single address.
% ---------------
\name{Author(s) Name(s)\thanks{Thanks to XYZ agency for funding.}}
\address{Author Affiliation(s)}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please edit your posting so that it actually produces an example of the type of problem you wish to solve.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please edit your code snippet into an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), i.e. make it a complete document (from `\documentclass` all the way to `\end{document}`) and remove unnecessary lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap multiple author names in a `{tabular}` environment. In this example I've just used a single `c` column with manually spaced names using `\qquad`, which is what the sample document uses for author spacing, but in principle you could also use tabular environment with more columns and `\qquad` as the intercolumn space.

```
\name{%
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
Author Name$^{\star \dagger}$ \qquad 
Author Name$^{\star}$ \qquad 
Author Name$^{\dagger}$\\ 
Author Name$^{\star \dagger}$ \qquad 
Author Name$^{\star}$ \qquad 
Author Name$^{\dagger}$
\end{tabular}}
%
 \address{$^{\star}$ Affiliation Number One \\
     $^{\dagger}$Affiliation Number Two}
```

[image: partial output]

Comment: You save my life. Thanks. It worked. I just have a small related question. If the two authors are selected as the corresponding author, how should I indicate it in the bottom of the first page as `$* Co-corresponding author`

Comment: @KimHee The footnotes for corresponding author are added with the `\sthanks` command, and there can be multiple instances of them. Each one will produce an automatic footnote mark (*, then † etc) so if you have multiple affiliations too, you should be careful how you choose the markers for those so that things don't get confusing.

Comment: @KimHee I've also made a slight change to the column specification to remove the column space at the beginning and end of the column.

Comment: Yes, sthanks will provide different mask. However, I want to group all corresponding author to one mask like `star. How should we do it